# Why does the CollectionViewSource need to be a resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, xaml-binding

I have the following situation, which works fine:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="csv" Source="{Binding Path=PropertyOnViewModel}">
      <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupByProperty" />
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

I tried changing it to

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <Binding>
      <Binding.Source>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=PropertyOnViewModel}">
          <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupByProperty" />
          </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
      </Binding.Source>
    </Binding>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

This does not work, it produces the runtime binding error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or 
FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=PropertyOnViewModel;
DataItem=null; target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=61730159); target
property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
```

What's the problem in the second version?

Comment: A binding without an explicit source object, like `{Binding Path=PropertyOnViewModel}` gets its source object from the DataContext of the element where it is declared. If that element does not have a DataContext (like a CollectionViewSource) the DataContext is retrieved from the next FrameworkElement up in the (logical) element tree. A ResourceDictionary forms such a tree, which means that the elements in the ResourceDictionary inherit their DataContext from the FrameworkElement that owns the ResourceDictionary.

Comment: A Binding in XAML does not form an element tree, hence no "governing FrameworkElement" can be found froim which the DataContext can be taken. [At least that is my understanding]

Comment: @Clemens I see. Any way to circumvent that? I tried to set the `ElementName` of the binding to the ListBox, and updated the `Path` to `DataContext.PropertyOnViewModel`, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Whats wrong with it being a resource? as a resource you can move it somewhere external if you want to reuse the same collectionviewsource. In my opinion it can be nothing but beneficial :)

Comment: @adminSoftDK Yes I'm most likely gonna leave it as a resource. I just want to understand why this does not work :)